# Trigger rsync on git checkout/pull

Tags: git, automation

My question may be naive but I can't figure it out...

Can I trigger an rsync or more generally a custom script, on a local repository when git commands are executed ? I tried looking into hooks but I'm not quite sure if these are supposed to/can be used in this case.

I also thought I should simply use git aliases to do these, but I am not sure what is dumb, stupid or idiot among my ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say git hooks are the best way to solve that task, because they were introduced for doing stuff like that:

*"Hooks are little scripts you can place in $GIT_DIR/hooks directory to trigger action at certain points."* - from [man githooks](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html)

Also, if you - or anybody else - would like to change the git `post-commit`-behaviour, i'd bet he'll have a first look into the `$GIT_DIR/hooks/`-directory.

But be aware that 3rd-party tools (like GUIs) may use an internal git implementation (like JGIT) which may unfortunately not call hooks!

Comment: and i would suggest to protocol the use of a hook-script in a README, so everybody is aware that there are sleeping dragons.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but in fact my point is to use a script that I only will execute assume that I don't want to push anything on a remote basis. Is ignoring hooks a decent approach to achieve this here ?

Comment: @aduch, creating a commit has nothing to do with pushing to remotes. It means you want invoke an action after a commit - the description in the git book may be better organized. They divided it into different sections, like server-side and [client-side-hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks).